# just another canBuildFrom question

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm going throught collection api and the returned type of operations which can modify the type of container and the type of contained element have all the header in its non-usecase form similar to the following:

```
def map [B, That] (f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]):That
```

It's clear that there is sure 'fallback' to other collection type with `That` (as in case of `BitSet` fallbacking to `Set` if the contained item is changed to other than `Int`). But how can one be sure of the type of the item? I would expect the return type to `That[B]`, but it is not.  Why? Educate me please :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already gave the answer yourself: If you want to be able to return a `BitSet` in appropriate cases, you need to get rid of that type parameter in the return type. There is no `BitSet[Int]`, obviously.

All the information you need is already handled by the appropriate `CanBuildFrom` implicits which have a fallback definition of the type `CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Traversable[A]]` (or whatever may be over `Traversable` in the type hierarchy).

Of course, the `CanBuildFrom` must be sensible but I think it’s actually possible to abuse it and return a truly strange `That`. Nonetheless, the defaults are pretty sane.